# Can anyone explain me why is this KEY_ID needed in SQLite Database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-sqlite

I'm following this [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/).

**onCreate()**: What does that INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT mean?

I can infer that it is the primarykey and it is auto incremented.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE books ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            "title TEXT, "+
            "author TEXT )";

    // create books table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
}
```

**Then in update() :**

```
 db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, //table
            values, // column/value
            KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) }); //selection args
```

1) I cannot understand how that ID works?  What does KEY_ID=? mean?

2) How it is incremented and

3) what initial value does it have - 0 or 1?

4) Do I need it for sure?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does that INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT mean?

INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT means that the variable (in this tutorial, the variable "id") is the type of integer (natural number), that it is the primary key in your database (that means that it is the unique identifier of the data in your database) and that it is autoincrementing whenever you add some row in the database.

> 1) I cannot understand how that ID works? What does KEY_ID=? mean?

The ID is the unique identifier for the rows in your database, you need this value to be able to access data correctly in your database. Example for the database in your tutorial:

```
id    title    author
 1    book1    author1
 2    book2    author2
 3    book2    author1
```

This is not the mistake for the third row in the database, the `id` is unique (different for every row because it is the primary key) but the rest can repeat itself (the "author1" and the "book2" are repeating values in the database). The `KEY_ID` is just the global variable defined in the `MySQLiteHelper` class that remembers the column `id`, so if we change the `id` column in the database to, for example, `identifier`, then to use that column in the code, we just need to replace `String KEY_ID = "id"` with the `String KEY_ID = "identifier"` and we are all set. The `KEY_ID=?` will just dynamically choose what rows to update based on `id` that is provided (by `book.getId()`)

> 2) How it is incremented and

The `KEY_ID` represents the `id` column in the database, and since the `id` it is set to `AUTOINCREMENT`, whenever you add a row in the database, the `id` value will be incremented (note that the `KEY_ID` is just a string representing the `id` column in the database, so it's not incrementing (cannot increment the word)).

> 3) what initial value does it have - 0 or 1?

The initial value of the `id` in the database is set to 1.

> 4) Do I need it for sure?

Well, the best way to identify the rows in your database is to use ids (variable `id` in the tutorial), and by making the "id" to be the `PRIMARY KEY` you ensure that there will be no duplicate values of it and that the "id" value will be used when searching for data in the database. Of course, you do not have to use it (in tutorial example, you have to), but if you can somehow find another unique identifier for your database rows, then I guess `id` is unecessary.

Hope this clarifies some things...

Comment: Nice explanation! It clarified everything! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd and 4th parameter of the `update` method define the `where` clause. I'd assume that `KEY_ID` is a constant with value "id" (just as a reminder primary keys in Android are named "_id" usually). The question mark (?) is a placeholder for any dynamic value you'd like to supply to the where clause. Those values are then provider by the 4th parameter of the method. In the end you'll have an SQL query with a where clause like this: `WHERE id = book.getId()` (book.getId() will be evaluated, not used as a string). Take a look at the [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) documentation - you'll notice all the CRUD operations support this way of providing selection statement and selection arguments.

Answer (score 0):

1) The ID is an unique identifier for SQL rows.
In SQL request, "?" is a parameter. So in your case, "?" will be remplaced by your selection args.

2) In your **onCreate()** method, "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" mean the id will be incremented automatically when you insert a new row, it's recommended to use this method because you don't need to manage it.

3) The initial value is 1.

4) Yes you need it !

Answer (score -1):

Initial value is 1, you can change whatever your start id.
it's automatically increase when you insert new row into data base.